# No such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am trying to automate a payment using selenium java via a modal. I am able to enter the CC details however when I exit the iframe and try to click the pay button I get the following error message

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294}) on port 11203
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Mar 19, 2021 3:35:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
7
cc details entered
default content
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="chakra-modal--body-630"]/button"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Joseffs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:cd7:6e5b:a729:ae56%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_281'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 89.0.4389.90, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c5002..., userDataDir: /var/folders/8h/ply4smss33q...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:64606}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: ebf1ef088c26a2c2d70561235a14f215
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id="chakra-modal--body-630"]/button}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at GsMarket.Market.main(Market.java:67)
```

My code is

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(baseURL);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Log in')]")).click();
    driver.findElementById("user_login").sendKeys(userName);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='password']")).sendKeys(password);
    
    // submit
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']")).click();

    // Shop Now Button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Shop Now')]")).click();


    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'2,000')]")).click();
    int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
    System.out.println(size);

//      // enter CC details
    driver.switchTo().frame(4);
    

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='cardnumber']")).sendKeys(CCNUM);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='exp-date']")).sendKeys(expiry);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='cvc']")).sendKeys(cvc);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='postal']")).sendKeys(zip);
    System.out.println("cc details entered");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    System.out.println("default content");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // Click purchase button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"chakra-modal--body-630\"]/button")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);;

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.close();
```

Comment: Short the error trace.It looks wast on Android:-)

Answer (score 1):

Use wait() method properly so that the desired element is visible/present.

Your code seems okay. You can recheck the xpath of button. Use click() method instead of
sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

```
 // Click purchase button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"chakra-modal--body-630\"]/button")).click();
```